Can I enter the US with a Canadian passport, without my green card?
I am flying from Canada to the US and I left my green card in the US. All I have with me is my Canadian passport. Will they let me into the US and onto my flight? If not what should I do?

Do you have an old immigrant visa, I-551 stamp, copy of your green card, I-485 approval notice, or some other proof of permanent residency?

Yes.  Citizens of Canada do not need an ESTA to enter the US, so you will be able to check in and make it as far as US immigration using only your Canadian passport.
Presuming you are flying from a major airport in Canada (ie, most of them for flights to the US) you will pass through US immigration before you leave Canada.  At the immigration counter you should state that you are a Permanent Resident and that you do not have your card with you.  They will potentially carry out some additional checks so you should allow some extra time - although realistically now days they will probably just make you look at a camera, confirm your biometrics, and let you pass through.

But the airline might ask them how long they plan to stay in the US as a visitor, if they don't have a green card or documentation of any other non-visitor status they plan to enter the US as.

@user102008 Canadian citizens do not need a return ticket to visit the US. It's not the job of airline staff to determine if a visitor is a bona fide visitor, only that they meet the requirements. And finally, airline staff in Canada are relatively lax in rule enforcement for flights to the US, as they know the passenger will pass through US immigration before boarding the flight.
